# filter DropDownList in mvc razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have Model in mvc razor. In this model(`EcotourismAttractions`) i have a list of Class `ParameterList`.

I want to have three `DropDownList` that filter item by `EntityType`.

First `DropDownList` show `EntityType` with value `1` second `DropDownList` `EntityType` with value `2` and third `DropDownList` shows  `EntityType` with value `3`.

For all `DropDownList` `Value` be Title of Parameters and Text be Id of Parameters.how can i do that???

```
 public class EcotourismAttractions
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string LatinName{ get; set; }
        public List<AreaManagement.Entities.Parameters> ParametersList{ get; set; }       

    }
public class Parameters {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public byte EntityType { get; set; } 
        public int ParentId { get; set; } 
        public string Title { get; set; } 
    }
```

Comment: we can do almost everything, but first please provide some format to your question so that it would become easy to read.

Comment: it is clear three DropDownList base on EntityType value

Comment: its better now, after editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to understand your question completely, always try to make your question look generic, if possible. Anyways best i can do is...

Create three IEnumerable for each dropdown.

```
public string Prop1 { get; set; }

public string Prop2 { get; set; }

public string Prop3 { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EntityType1List { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EntityType2List { get; set; }

public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EntityType3List { get; set; }
```

Initialize the list  with desired values.

```
EntityType1List = new SelectList(ParametersList.Where(x=>x.EntityType == 1).ToList(), "Value","Text").ToList();

EntityType1List = new SelectList(ParametersList.Where(x=>x.EntityType == 2).ToList(), "Value","Text").ToList();

EntityType1List = new SelectList(ParametersList.Where(x=>x.EntityType == 3).ToList(), "Value","Text").ToList();
```

Render on view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Prop1 , new SelectList(Model.EntityType1List , "Value", "Text", Model.Prop1))

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Prop2, new SelectList(Model.EntityType2List , "Value", "Text", Model.Prop2))

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Prop3, new SelectList(Model.EntityType3List , "Value", "Text", Model.Prop3))
```

Comment: Prop1, Prop2, Prop3 is you model property that will hold selected value of the dropdown at the time of form post. Like any other Model property say public string FirstName {get;set;} and @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.FirstName)

Comment: Last ToList() in Initialize the list with desired values is incorrect

Comment: It won't give you an error , but yes of course we can omit this.